# rvalue hello world missing constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I'm trying to know more about rvalue references but I got stuck on this simplest example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct C {
    C() { cout << "C()\n"; }
    ~C() { cout << "~C()\n"; }
    C(const C&) { cout << "C(const C&)\n"; }
    C& operator=(const C&) { cout << "operator=(const C&)\n"; return *this; }

    C(C&&) { cout << "C(C&&)\n"; }
    C& operator=(C&&) { cout << "operator=(C&&)\n"; return *this; }
};

C foo() { C c; return c; }

int main()
{
    const C c = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

I've compiled it with Clang 3.2 and `-std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors` (to avoid (N)RVO) but the result is surprising to me:

```
C()
~C()    // huh?
C(C&&)
~C()
~C()
```

I expected exactly that except for the first `~C()`. Where did it came from and what am I missing because there are 2 constructions and 3 destructions? Is the && constructor called with a destroyed object reference??

Comment: Step through it in a debugger and see where the calls are coming from. You're right that the number of constructor calls and the number of destructor calls should be the same.

Comment: I got this http://liveworkspace.org/code/IlzNk$0 which is what is expected

Comment: @SethCarnegie: but you selected GCC 4.7.2 didn't you? I tried selecting clang 3.2 and I get the output shown by the OP

Comment: @Seth Carnegie you link to gcc 4.7.2 output which seems correct. Could that mean I stumbled upon some clang oddities?

Comment: @AndyProwl and chrisaverage yes, it could be that clang has a bug, because I don't see how you can have more destructors than constructors, and you've written the functions for all the ways an object can be constructed/assigned. I'm going to try something, hold on a second.

Comment: There's this old question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241448/is-clang-xcode-4-4-1-buggy-when-fno-elide-constructors-is-set where the answer points to a Clang bug report. Not sure if that bug still exists and if it's behind the results the OP is getting here.

Comment: Yep, see http://liveworkspace.org/code/140VyL$0 GCC prints the correct values and strangely clang prints nothing, so unless I made some other mistake it's a bug.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: indeed. I tried this http://liveworkspace.org/code/wISyv$30 and it seems that the destructor for the local object constructed in `foo()` is called before the temporary is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This must be a bug. The destructor for the local object constructed in `foo()` is being invoked before the move constructor of the receiving object. In particular, **it seems a temporary is allocated but not (move-)constructed** when returning by value. The following program shows this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct C 
{
    C(int z) { id = z; cout << "C():" << id << endl; }
    ~C() { cout << "~C():" << id << endl; }
    C(const C& c) { id = c.id + 1; cout << "C(const C&):" << id << endl; }
    C& operator=(const C&) { cout << "operator=(const C&)\n"; return *this; }
    C(C&& c) { id = c.id + 1; cout << "C(C&&):" << id << endl;}
    C& operator=(C&&) { cout << "operator=(C&&)\n"; return *this; }
    int id;
};

C foo() { C c(10); return c; }

int main()
{
    const C c = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C():10
// THE TEMPORARY OBJECT IS PROBABLY ALLOCATED BUT *NOT CONSTRUCTED* HERE...
~C():10 // DESTRUCTOR CALLED BEFORE ANY OTHER OBJECT IS CONSTRUCTED!
C(C&&):4198993
~C():4198992
~C():4198993
```

Creating *two* objects inside of `foo()` seems to shed some more light on the issue:

```
C foo() { C c(10); C d(14); return c; }
```

Output:

```
C():10
C():14
~C():14
// HERE, THE CONSTRUCTOR OF THE TEMPORARY SHOULD BE INVOKED!
~C():10
C(C&&):1 // THE OBJECT IN main() IS CONSTRUCTED FROM A NON-CONSTRUCTED TEMPORARY
~C():0 // THE NON-CONSTRUCTED TEMPORARY IS BEING DESTROYED HERE
~C():1
```

Interestingly, this seems to depend on how the object is constructed in `foo()`. If `foo()` is written this way:

```
C foo() { C c(10); return c; }
```

Then the error appears. If it is written this way it does not:

```
C foo() { return C(10); }
```

Output with this last definition of `foo()`:

```
C():10 // CONSTRUCTION OF LOCAL OBJECT
C(C&&):11 // CONSTRUCTION OF TEMPORARY
~C():10 // DESTRUCTION OF LOCAL OBJECT
C(C&&):12 // CONSTRUCTION OF RECEIVING OBJECT
~C():11 // DESTRUCTION OF TEMPORARY
~C():12 // DESTRUCTION OF RECEIVING OBJECT
```

Comment: What's curious is that this works as expected: C foo() { return C(10); }. Seems like a very specific code path bug. I'll accept this answer then.

Comment: @chrisaverage: i think the problem is quite general. If `foo()` is written this way: `C foo() { C c(10); return c; }` then it gives the error. Only if it is written this way it does not: `C foo() { return C(10); }`

Comment: What I meant is that it only occurs when the object is a candidate for NRVO but not RVO. The bug report mentioned by Michael in the original comments seems to confirm this.